# Is there a way in Kotlin Retrofit that works equivalent as OnPreExecute of Kotlin AsyncTask?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a `MainActivity.kt`that call service provided by a`NetworkConfig.kt` class (I'm quite a beginner in Android Development).

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        NetworkConfig().getService()
            .getUsers()
            .enqueue(object : Callback<List<UserDataClassItem>> {

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<UserDataClassItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No Connection. Check your Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<UserDataClassItem>>,
                    response: Response<List<UserDataClassItem>>
                ) {
                    rvUser.adapter = UserAdapter(response.body())
                }
            })
    }
}
```

**NetworkConfig.kt**

```
class NetworkConfig {
    // set interceptor
    private fun getInterceptor() : OkHttpClient {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build()
    }

    private fun getRetrofit() : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .client(getInterceptor())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    fun getService() = getRetrofit().create(Users::class.java)
}


//Access https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
interface Users {
    @GET("users")
    fun getUsers(): Call<List<UserDataClassItem>>
}
```

What I want to know is that is there a way in Retrofit to execute a task when the App is fetching the service on background (Such as showing a progressBar) ?
Something that works equivalent as AsyncTask's [onPreExecute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onPreExecute()) function.

If there's anything unclear, let me know.

Comment: Actually, before you call NetworkConfig().getService().getUsers() it like `onPreExcecute` you should show loading and hide loading in `onResponse` and `onFailure`

Comment: use RxJava call factory and implement `onSubscribe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit enqueue will execute in Asynchronous way

```
//You could show progress bar here
NetworkConfig().getService()
        .getUsers()
        .enqueue(object : Callback<List<UserDataClassItem>> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<UserDataClassItem>>, t: Throwable) {
//You could hide progressBar here
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No Connection. Check your Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<UserDataClassItem>>,
                response: Response<List<UserDataClassItem>>
            ) {
               //You could hide progressBar here
                rvUser.adapter = UserAdapter(response.body())
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Before your network call you can set your `ProgressBar` visibility to `View.VISIBLE`, and then in your Retrofit's `onResponse()` and `onFailure()`, set its visibility to `View.GONE`.

Like this:

```
progressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
NetworkConfig().getService()
.getUsers()
.enqueue(object : Callback<List<UserDataClassItem>> {

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<UserDataClassItem>>, t: Throwable) {
        progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No Connection. Check your Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<List<UserDataClassItem>>,
        response: Response<List<UserDataClassItem>>
    ) {
        progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
        rvUser.adapter = UserAdapter(response.body())
    }
})
```